# how to load a new component by replacing an existing component in angular router

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing, angular-router

I have customerList component in which i am getting data from a service and rendering the data.
In each row if i am clicking on any name, i am trying to render to a new CustomerDetail component with different header and content.
I am able to load CustomerDetail component but its coming  below customerList component.

i tried to solve by routing, its not happening

app.component.html

---

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
</div>
<customer-list></customer-list>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

customerList.component.html

---

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let customer">
              <nav>
                <a href routerLink="/customer" routerLinkActive="true" (click)="onSelect(customer)">{{customer.customerName}}</a>
              </nav>
        </mat-cell>
```

customerList.component.ts

---

```
 onSelect(customer){
    console.log('onSelect method calls');
    console.log(customer);
    this.router.navigate(['/customer',customer.customerName]);
  }
```

app-routing.module.ts

---

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: CustomerListComponent },
  {path:'customer/:customerName', component : CustomerDetailComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: If my answer has helped you and is correct please mark it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `<customer-list>` from you app.component.html

Add a catch-all route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: CustomerListComponent },
  { path:'customer/:customerName', component : CustomerDetailComponent},
  // Add this route
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
];
```

Furthermore change the link to:

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/customer', customer.customerName]">{{customer.customerName}}</a>
```

Comment: I changed as u said, but after clicking on the name, that component is not loading

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: CustomerListComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' },
  {path:'customer/:customerName', component : CustomerDetailComponent}
];



<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

Comment: Can you remove the `routerLink="/customer" routerLinkActive="true" `?

Comment: Have a look at my answer you still have to update the `<a>` link in the customerList.component.html

Comment: now done, actually that sequence in routing module matters. In my routing module the sequence was not correct. Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194691/discussion-between-daniel-habenicht-and-mohan).

Comment: Is there anything else I have to include in my answer?